# make bash abort when proces does not abort and vice versa

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make by bash script do a "not" on an abort so that when a called script returns ok it aborts, and vice versa when it does not abort.

I'm trying this like

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
my_process || echo "Program failed as expected. Good!" 
my_process  ; echo "Program did not fail as expected. Bad!" ;   exit -1
```

but i don't see how to combine the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if my_process; then
    echo "Program did not fail as expected. Bad!" 
    exit -1
else
    echo "Program failed as expected. Good!" 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `if`/`else`, you could use the `&&` and `||` operators with [groups](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) of commands:

```
my_process && { echo "Program did not fail as expected. Bad!"; exit -1; } \
    || echo "Program failed as expected. Good!"
```

Comment: This is a dangerous pattern. `a && b || c` will run `c` if `b` is unsuccessful. To wit, `if true; then false; else launch_nukes; fi` is harmless, whereas `true && false || launch_nukes` is the jumping off point for my WarGames 2 screenplay.

Answer (score 2):

Extending from John's answer, using your shorthand:

```
! my_process && echo "Program failed as expected. Good!" || echo "Program did not fail as expected. Bad!" && exit -1
```

The `!` operator negates the conditional boolean, so you can use `&& .. || ..`.

**EDIT** Note that this isn't nearly as clear as John's much more useable code - just to show you can do it with the ternary-style syntax. Prefer the readability of [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900290/171318).

Comment: John's attempt is much more clear, readable and extensible. No need for a shorthand

Comment: @hek2mgl Sure there isn't, just to show it can be done using the ternary-style syntax too.